# Floating point and LU decomposition

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, floating-point

So in a numerical linear algebra book I'm studying (Matrix Computations 4th edition) there is this example on floating points and LU decomposition:

*Suppose 3-digit floating point arithmetic is used to solve (with gaussian elimination without pivoting):*

$\begin{pmatrix}
.001 & 1\\ 
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}  \\ 
x_{2} 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
3 
\end{pmatrix}$

*Applying Gaussian elimination we get:*

$L=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
1000 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
and
$U=\begin{pmatrix}
.001 & 1\\ 
0 & 1000
\end{pmatrix}$

**Here's what I don't get**.

I calculated $U$ as such:

$m=(0,\frac{a_{21}}{a_{11}})^T=(0,1000)^T$

$M=I_2-m*e_1^T=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
 0\\ 
 1000
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
-1000 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Now  $U=MA=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
-1000 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
.001 & 1\\ 
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

$\Leftrightarrow U=\begin{pmatrix}
.001 & 1\\ 
0 & 2-10^3
\end{pmatrix}$

So now I have to calculate $fl(2-10^3)$ in the 3-digit floating arithmetic

$2-10^3=0.002*10^3-1.000*10^3=-0.998*10^3$

But since it's 3-digit floating arithmetic there is no reason for rounding the number. So U is 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
.001 & 1\\ 
0 & 998
\end{pmatrix}$$

The way I see it for $U$ to be as given by the example the floating arithmetic should either be 2-digit or the number should be somethin like $0.9998$

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Each step of your calculation must round to 3 digits. You can't just round at the end. Can you show your steps to find $U$?

Comment: I edited my answer so you can see the process. I don't see anywhere more than 3 digits so I don't really get where I miss the rounding

Comment: Between $2-10^3=\ldots=-0.998*10^3$, you perform the sum with 4 digit precision instead of 3 digit.

Comment: Sorry I might be confused but doesn't 3-digit mean the mantissa is 3? Meaning that there should be 3 decimal places?

Comment: There are four digits in the following mantissas: $0.002$ and $1.000$ (maybe $1.234$ helps).

Comment: Oh ok. I thought the mantissa is the digits after the decimal point. Thanks